# Squid, just log user petitions

Tags: logging, proxy, squid

I'm working on a squid configuration under raspberry3 and Ubuntu.

I want to select what the log stores. Is there a way in squid not to log everything, just the user URL petition.

**Example.**
*For example when the client ask WWW.A.COM its log the site and all the site components. 
I want to keep record just of WWW.A.com not the libraries or resources the site ask for.*

So far i couldn't find anything in regard of this.

I would like to reduce the size of the log file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

squid's log format is pretty configurable.. http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.5/cfgman/logformat.html

But you should also ensure that you make proper use of tools like logrotate that can compress/archive/delete log files based on age/size constraints.

Comment: I dont seem to find a way to tell apart the original petition made from the client from another make from sub-requests made to ask libraries or publicity. Thanks for your time